# Facebook Credits on an external website

Tags: javascript, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-credits

I tryed the sample code found here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/creditsapi/
Even if i added my company address & payment, i still get this error:

> API Error Code: 1151 API Error Description: Sorry, but this app may
>   not be eligible to accept Facebook Credits. If this app has accepted
>   credits before, please try again. Error Message: Invalid Application

I think the credits api best work on iframe apps. Is possible to integrate credits in my website? 
Best
Matteo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

credits only work in facebook canvas apps:

> The Facebook Credits API enables a user to use credits as a method for
>   purchasing digital and virtual goods within a Facebook canvas
>   application. Please note: the credits api is not yet available for use
>   by external websites but only on canvas iframe applications.

Comment: The Facebook policy about using credits on external websites seems to have changed since the question was answered. I think the answer is no longer true since the quote from Facebook documentation can't be found anymore.

Comment: @DanielRistic : the question and the answer is not related to Facebook policy but to the scope of credits API support. You can read through the doc linked above. It didn't change (supported on canvas apps and mobile web apps only).

Answer (score 1):

The error is because you do not have a valid application id. You are going to have to create an application for your website. This can be done by going to https://developers.facebook.com/apps . If you have an application made for your website still go to the website and grab the App ID/API Key and put after

```
 FB.init({appId:
```

Comment: Hi, i'm using this to start the code:  FB.init({
     appId  : '1674xxx',
     status : true, // check login status
     cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
   });        What is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

What I do is redirect the user into the iFrame canvas for payment and then back out to my web site when done.

Not sure this breaks any Facebook agreement.